# Pyspark replace + with space

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, split, regexp-replace

Hey I have a string coulmn like this:

```
|plus+size+2+piece+dresses+for+women+size
|how+are+you
|why+did+you+come
```

Now I want to replace all the `+` with `{space}`. I have tried `regex_replace`, `split` but nothing is working as `+` is a reserved character. This is the error I'm getting:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0
+
```

Can someone tell me how can I replace `+`

Comment: Add \ to escape the special char. (\+). ref: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html#:~:text=Escape%20Sequences%20(%5Cchar)%3A,regex%20%5C(%20matches%20%22(%22%20.